# Adding arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have a 2D array:

```
1.007, 0.003, 0.003
0.0095, 2.003, 0.007
1.005, 0.008, 0.001
0.003, 6.884, 0.007
```

How can I go through the columns such that I get an average of the numbers greater than 1? Such as: (1.007+1.005)/2 = 1.006

```
[1.006, 4.4435, 0]
```

I wrote this so far. Been working on it for days, but I can't get it to work.

```
double sum=0;
for(int j = 0; j <data[0].length; ++j) { // col
    for( int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { // row
        if (data[i][j]>=1){
            sum=sum+data[i][j];
            System.out.println(sum);
            // j+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

data is my 2D array.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the numbers '[1.006, 4.4435, 0]' are computed? For example, what numbers sum to 1.006?

Comment: Edited my answer according to your edits of question

Answer (score 1):

If you need to go through columns, switch the for-loop order

```
public class ArrayExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] data = {
                {1.007, 0.003, 0.003},
                {0.0095, 2.003, 0.007},
                {1.005, 0.008, 0.001},
                {0.003, 6.884, 0.007}
        };

        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
                if (data[i][j] >= 1.0) {
                    sum += data[i][j];
                    System.out.println(sum);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gives

```
1.007
3.01
4.015
10.899000000000001
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited according last edit of question:

```
  double[][] data = {
                {1.007, 0.003, 0.003},
                {0.0095, 2.003, 0.007},
                {1.005, 0.008, 0.001},
                {0.003, 6.884, 0.007}
        };

        double sum;
        int count;

        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            sum = 0;
            count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i][j] >= 1.0) {
                    sum += data[i][j];
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count!=0){
                System.out.print(sum/count + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(0);
            }

        }
    }
```

Result:
`1.0059999999999998 4.4435 0`